# Power Point Presentations: filesize and background music

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I've got a little problem with my powerpoint presentations (actually there are 2 problems).

Basically my presentations feature quite a few images combined with some text and animations. So they become pretty large - slides and file size on hdd (yes the pictures are quite large, but I'm doing my best to minimize them). I have a presentation with about 25 slides resulting in 12 megabytes. Other presentations are way larger, but since this one is already causing problems I'd like to fix them here first.

So here's questions number 1: Can anyone recommend a way/tool/best practice to reduce the filesize of my presentation? I haven't really tried a lot since I don't really know where to start outside of reducing my images via photoshop. So maybe there is some way to compress the whole presentation (my images are already jpg so zipping doesn't to the trick).

The second issue is about background music. Does anyone know how I can add a song (just one) so it's played in the background while the presentation is running? I tried to embbed a .wav file but those files are quite huge. Sadly every time I tried to add a .mp3 file it's lost when I send the presentation to someone else. Maby these music-formats are the wrong ones in the first place and .wmv might be the better choise (haven't tried this one).

I'm regularly recieving presentations featuring a bunch of nice looking images and background music that are working just fine and aren't nearly as large as my presentations in terms of file size. So must be room for improvement on my side.
Maybe I'm doing this all wrong and someone of you can push me in the right direction ...

That's it so far ;-) Thanks in advance guys. Regards, Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

remember that even though you have 'high resolution images', if you're showing them on a low resolution projector or display, it doesn't matter. The chain is only as strong as it's weakest link, so to speak. Nothing else you can do besides limiting the 'extras' that you embed.

Lastly, to add background music just add audio from your PC (See screenshots). You didn't indicate which version of powerpoint you're using, but I've attached screenshots from 2013.

---

[image]

---

After adding the audio, you have the option of having it play across slides also.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm wondering if I can still email the presentation to other people when images and music are just referenced instead of embedded. Do I have to send all files or is it enough to solely send the powerpoint file? I'm not planning to show my presentations to a larger audience using projectors (at least not regularly). I much rather like to share these presentations with friends via email.

Comment: I also don't really know the difference between pptx and ppsx files other than the first can be edited and the latter just viewed. Would it be an option to reference my pictures and music and then save the presentation as ppsx? Again, do I have to send all files or is the ppsx file enough?

Comment: I edited my answer, I don't think the newer powerpoints can be linked without being embedded actually, for the reason you mentioned, so I removed that portion of my answer. afaik ppsx files are the slideshow themselves, so theoretically yes, you should be able to create your powerpoint and then save as a ppsx, and people can view them?

Comment: Images, sounds, movies and the like can all still be linked; when you insert them, there's a triangle next to the INSERT button.  Click that and you'll see the option to link.  If you put movies/sounds in the same folder as the saved PPT/PPTX BEFORE inserting them, the links will be path-free.  As long as they end up in the same folder as the PPT/PPTX/etcX on the recipient's system, they should work, assuming the recipient has the right codecs etc.